# Managing GIT Flow when multiple developers are working on the same file

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, cherry-pick

I have been working on a large scale project which is causing conflicts when multiple developers end up working on the same file in the same repo.

Here is an example of the scenario:

Assume there are 2 developers, Foo and Bar. Foo needs to make changes on test.txt with 2 new lines of code. Sometime later Bar also wants to make changes on test.txt with 2 new lines (not the same as Foo's code) - What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Usually, a feature branch is created for every feature and once the branch has been fully tested, it gets merged into a release branch which is deployed into STG and PROD and then merged into master.

An added level of complexity, for some reason, we do not want to go ahead with the change that Foo made, we just want to go ahead with the changes that Bar made. How do we achieve that scenario? In this case, Foo made the commit first and Bar did it later, making cherry-picking difficult.

Assumptions:

- Both developers are working on the same feature branch.
- Foo did the first commit on the feature branch
- Bar did the second commit on the same file

Comment: *Making cherry-picking difficult* that's what you get when you let multiple people work on the same branch. Your only option is to swap the commits around so that you can merge Bar's changes first. That will lead to merge conflicts during the rebase operation. Such is life. You can't get away with that difficulty now. Perhaps, some coordination between the two could have mitigated the difficulty, but I am sure you know that.

Comment: @j6t, yep I totally get that. The scenario here is a bit different though. For some reason, it has been decided that Bar's changes are going into prod and not Foo's. Ideally both were supposed to go into prod. It's not in their hands. I agree it's kinda weird, but that's the situation I'm in!

Comment: If you can deliver a part without the other, is it really the same feature ?
Use a maximum of branch is the best

Comment: I dont think using a different branch would solve this problem - can you please explain? My understanding is that if they start using different branches, and since they will be working on the same file, there will be conflicts when they are being merged!

Answer (score -1):

You should split the file, there is no reason to let multiple developers working on the same file in the same time. Conflicts and overlaps will give you extra workhours every time. My suggestion is to restructure/split your files.you will not get the right solution anyway.